# Trying to build a recursion function using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I'm currently trying to build a function that traverse through a nested object looking for a value that matches. I created this custom code that checks each levels of object. The problem how can repeat the function multiple times until it fetches or match with the value I'm looking for traversing to multiple levels.

```js
let animalTree = {
    "animals":[
      {
        "species":"Vertebrates", 
        "types": [
            {
                "category": "Fish",
            },
            {
                "category": "Amphibians",
            },
            {
                "category": "Reptiles",
            },
            {
                "category": "Birds",
            },
            {
                "category": "Mammals",
            }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "species":"Invertebrates", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Annelids", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Molluscs", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Nematodes", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Arthropods", 
      },
    ],
}





let scanTree = () => {

    let matchValue = "Vertebrates";

    for (let i = 0; i < animalTree.length; i++){

        if (animalTree[i].species == matchValue){
            console.log('Found')
        }
    }
}

let jParse = JSON.stringify(animalTree);

scanTree();
```

Comment: Is it like your match value can be either `category` of `specie` why do you want to run your function recursively ?

Comment: sub elements must have the same keyname

Comment: If there where a second item in your JSON what would that look like? Are you saying there could be another `animals` object? Your question is a little confusing - you shouldn't need to write your own function for this..

Comment: @mickl yes, match value can be a species or category

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. JSON is a text format. What you have is an object. No need for any (additional) special jargon.

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry my mistake. I sometimes get confused of  the difference between object and JSON

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your key names might be so providing generic function using `Object.values()` - let me know if you only expect key names to be species - will simplify then

```js
let animalTree = {
    "animals":[
      {
        "species":"Vertebrates", 
        "types": [
            {
                "category": "Fish",
            },
            {
                "category": "Amphibians",
            },
            {
                "category": "Reptiles",
            },
            {
                "category": "Birds",
            },
            {
                "category": "Mammals",
            }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "species":"Invertebrates", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Annelids", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Molluscs", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Nematodes", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Arthropods", 
      },
    ],
}

let matchValue = "Birds";

let scan = (array) => {
  for(let item of array) {      
      for(let value of Object.values(item)){
          if(typeof value === "string" && value === matchValue) {
              return item;
          } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
             return scan(value);
          }
      }
  }
}


let result = scan(animalTree.animals);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify()` and a regular expression to simplify things:

```
const scanTree = (str) => { 
   const arr = JSON.stringify(animalTree).match(/"\w+":\s?"\w+"/g);
   const res = arr.filter((el) => el.indexOf(str) > -1);
   return res.map(val => JSON.parse("{" + val + "}"));
}
```

```js
const animalTree = {
    "animals":[
      {
        "species":"Vertebrates", 
        "types": [
            {
                "category": "Fish",
            },
            {
                "category": "Amphibians",
            },
            {
                "category": "Reptiles",
            },
            {
                "category": "Birds",
            },
            {
                "category": "Mammals",
            }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "species":"Invertebrates", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Annelids", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Molluscs", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Nematodes", 
      },
      {
        "species":"Arthropods", 
      },
    ],
};

const scanTree = (str) => { 
   const arr = JSON.stringify(animalTree).match(/"\w+":\s?"\w+"/g);
   const res = arr.filter((el) => el.indexOf(str) > -1);
   return res.map(val => JSON.parse("{" + val + "}"));
}

console.log(scanTree("Birds"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let animalTree = {
        "animals":[
          {
            "species":"Vertebrates", 
            "types": [
                {
                    "category": "Fish",
                },
                {
                    "category": "Amphibians",
                },
                {
                    "category": "Reptiles",
                },
                {
                    "category": "Birds",
                },
                {
                    "category": "Mammals",
                }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            "species":"Invertebrates", 
          },
          {
            "species":"Annelids", 
          },
          {
            "species":"Molluscs", 
          },
          {
            "species":"Nematodes", 
          },
          {
            "species":"Arthropods", 
          },
        ],
    }

    let scanTree = () => {
        var flag = 0;
        let matchValue = "Vertebrates";
        for(let i = 0 ; i < animalTree.animals.length ; i++ ){
            if(animalTree.animals[i].species == matchValue){
                flag = 1;
                console.log("found");
                break;
            }
            else{
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if(!flag){
            console.log("not found")
        }
    }

    //let jParse = JSON.stringify(animalTree);

    scanTree();
```

Try this one.